# How to customize billing address selection

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-address, billing-address, billing

i'm try to customize the billing select in "/checkout/#payment" i found the file list.html with this code

```
<div class="field field-select-billing">
<label class="label"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Billing Address'"></span></label>
<div class="control" data-bind="if: (addressOptions.length > 1)">
    <select class="" name="billing_address_id" data-bind="
    options: addressOptions,
    optionsText: addressOptionsText,
    value: selectedAddress,
    event: {change: onAddressChange(selectedAddress())};
"></select>
</div>
```

and i don't know how to customize it using javascript o jquery see that it is a HTML file. i would from this

[image]

get something like that or like the default block of magento "customer/account"

[image]

(I'm using Magento 2.3.3)

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_shipping_methods.html

Comment: i don't want to customize shipping but billing. Is it the same procedure?

Comment: apply the same procedure in billing that link was just a reference for you